# Use Multiple google bigquery service accounts in Power BI (Service & Desktop)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, powerbi, dataset, credentials

I'm trying to configure  multiple  Dataset in Power BI Service to use different service accounts for different projects GCP.
Every time i publish a new dataset using a different google service account , it is always associated with the previous bigquery datasource overriding the credentials.
Fits this use case :
[image]

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: connect to gcp projects through Power BI using different service accounts. it's impossible !

Comment: Yes, it is impossible. But Microsoft and Google are working together for a better integration. Maybe something new by the end of the year...

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere do you have the source where i can follow the progress ...

Comment: No, I haven't. A friend of mine works in a large and famous company and has requested Google and Microsoft to improve their interoperability. Because it's a real big company, the 2 have agreed to improve the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Have same issue, microsoft says it is products limitation. and suggested to use Power BI Data Gateway.

it works fine with power bi data gateway.
I do understand a data gateway is not required as GCP is Cloud source but we have considered this as a interim setup.

Answer (score 0):

For each dashboard you have to set "Confidentiality level setting for this data source" to "Private".

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same issue.
Trying to apply your solution, unfortunately this is not working. when changing project A cred, it Changes project B cred.
Additionally, I am wondering how would it be if we were tyring to get 2 projects on the same dataset

Best Regard

Olivier LN ([LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/olivier-le-nard/))